# Roblox making functions run more than once

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

My code:

```
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Mouse = Player:GetMouse()
local Activation = 
Instance.new("Sound",game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Head)
local char = Player.Character
local hum = char.Humanoid
local root = char.HumanoidRootPart

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.F then
    local animation = Instance.new("Animation")
    animation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://1581972610"
    local animTrack = hum:LoadAnimation(animation)
    animTrack:Play()
    Activation.SoundId = "rbxassetid://1581091676" --Plays Mangekyou Sharingan Activation Sound.
    Activation:Play()
    wait(0.3)       
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Head.face.Texture = "rbxassetid://76285632" --When F is pressed, face texture changes to sharingan decal.
    game:GetService("Chat"):Chat(Player.Character.Head, "Mangekyou Sharingan!")
end
end)

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.R then
    Activation.SoundId = "rbxassetid://1580990602" --Plays Amaterasu Activation Sound.
    Activation:Play()
    game:GetService("Chat"):Chat(Player.Character.Head, "Amaterasu!")
    local Target = Instance.new("Part") --makes a part
    Target.CFrame = Mouse.Hit; --Makes part spawn at the mouse's current location in game
    Target.Parent = game.Workspace
    Target.Transparency = 1 
    Target.Anchored = true 
    Target.CanCollide = false 



    local Amaterasu = Instance.new("Fire")
    Amaterasu.Parent = game.Workspace.Part
    Amaterasu.Color = Color3.new(0,0,0)
    Amaterasu.SecondaryColor = Color3.new(0,0,0) --amaterasu properties
    Amaterasu.Size = 25

    local R = Instance.new("RocketPropulsion") --rocket propulsion, parents amaterasu
    R.Parent = Amaterasu
    R.MaxThrust = 300
    R.ThrustP = 30
    R:Fire()
end
end)

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.G then
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Head.face.Texture = "rbxassetid://22557247" --When G is pressed, face texture changes back to normal.(leaves face blank isnt working :/)
end
end)
```

I am working on the second function in this script, the one that activates if the "r" key is pressed. The function makes a part spawn to the mouses current location with flames inside of it by pressing the "r" key.

This works all fine except after the first time I press "r" to spawn the part at my mouse location, if I move my mouse's location to another area and press "r" again it repeats everything in the function but doesn't change to the new location.

Comment: Do you mean this line ` Target.CFrame = Mouse.Hit ` resulting in the same position? Well, you'll have to check what is assigned here. Might be that `Mouse` instance needs to be updated each time.

Answer (score 0):

You should try running `Mouse = Player:GetMouse()` inside your function that runs if they press the R key, to update the mouse's location. Your updated event would look like:

```
UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.R then
    Mouse = Player:GetMouse() --This line updates the mouse and presumably, its location.
    Activation.SoundId = "rbxassetid://1580990602"Sound.
    Activation:Play()
    game:GetService("Chat"):Chat(Player.Character.Head, "Amaterasu!")
    local Target = Instance.new("Part")
    Target.CFrame = Mouse.Hit;
    --All the other stuff you're doing goes here
```

This way, the mouse's location is updated every time the if block is entered (which is every time the user presses R).