# Roblox, damaging a player upon contact with a part

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

My code:

```
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Mouse = Player:GetMouse()
local Activation = 
Instance.new("Sound",game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Head)
local char = Player.Character
local hum = char.Humanoid
local root = char.HumanoidRootPart

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.F then
local animation = Instance.new("Animation")
animation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://1581972610"
local animTrack = hum:LoadAnimation(animation)
animTrack:Play()
Activation.SoundId = "rbxassetid://1581091676" --Plays Mangekyou Sharingan Activation Sound.
Activation:Play()
wait(0.3)       
game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Head.face.Texture = "rbxassetid://76285632" --When F is pressed, face texture changes to sharingan decal.
game:GetService("Chat"):Chat(Player.Character.Head, "Mangekyou Sharingan!")
end
end)

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.R then
Activation.SoundId = "rbxassetid://1580990602" --Plays Amaterasu Activation Sound.
Activation:Play()
game:GetService("Chat"):Chat(Player.Character.Head, "Amaterasu!")
local Target = Instance.new("Part") --makes a part
Target.CFrame = Mouse.Hit; --Makes part spawn at the mouse's current location in game
Target.Parent = game.Workspace
Target.Transparency = 1 
Target.Anchored = true 
Target.CanCollide = false 



local Amaterasu = Instance.new("Fire")
Amaterasu.Parent = game.Workspace.Part
Amaterasu.Color = Color3.new(0,0,0)
Amaterasu.SecondaryColor = Color3.new(0,0,0) --amaterasu properties
Amaterasu.Size = 25

local R = Instance.new("RocketPropulsion") --rocket propulsion, parents amaterasu
R.Parent = Amaterasu
R.MaxThrust = 300
R.ThrustP = 30
R:Fire()
end
end)

 UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.G then
game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Head.face.Texture = "rbxassetid://22557247" --When G is pressed, face texture changes back to normal.(leaves face blank isnt working :/)
end
end)
```

I am working on the second function in this script, the one that activates if the "r" key is pressed. The function makes a part spawn to the mouses current location with flames inside of it by pressing the "r" key.

This works all fine. I want the flames that spawn to damage any player it touches for a certain amount of health, in this case I want the damage to be 100 health.

Comment: This is mostly a copy-and-paste [of your question from two hours earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664450/roblox-making-functions-run-more-than-once). The code was also supplied in a third question some seven hours before that one. I would therefore say you're asking questions in a way that creates essentially duplicate material, and in a way that risks creating duplicate effort.

Comment: I appreciate that posting the same (or similar) questions may increase your chances of getting answers, but note that Stack Overflow is somewhat curated, and not all questions are accepted. My advice, for what it is worth, is to wait to get an answer on one question before posting again. You may find that a question becomes redundant by virtue of the prior question being solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is Touched - see Creating a Dangerous Trap: https://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Creating_Traps_and_Pickups

Example provided in documentation:

```
local trapPart = script.Parent
local function onPartTouch(otherPart)

    local partParent = otherPart.Parent
    local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")

    if ( humanoid ) then
        -- Set player's health to 0
        humanoid.Health = 0
    end
end

trapPart.Touched:Connect(onPartTouch)
```

But disclaimer - not a Roblox dev (just bugging one right now).

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make your parent before setting properties otherwise it causes performance lag